How to use IBM's CUA for mark copy delete paste in emacs
How do I configure emacs to use IBM CUA keys for mark copy delete and paste?
IBM CUA keys use C-Ins and S-Ins for copy and paste.
I find M-w and C-y difficult to use and would prefer to use what I'm more comfortable with.b

C-h f cua-mode. Although I see that it does not follow the IBM convention you mention...

You mention "CUA keys", but I think this is confusing people, because you aren't talking about "C-x", "C-c" and "C-v", which are what Emacs's cua-mode makes usable for cut, copy and paste.  In your question, you mention "C-" and "S-".  And in one of your comments, you mention shift-selection.  But those things are usable in Emacs by default, with no configuration at all.  So maybe you have inadvertently disabled them?

You can bind the desired keys using the bind-key function.
In your init file :
(use-package bind-key
    :defer t
    :ensure t
    :bind
    (:map global-map
          (("C-<insert>" . kill-ring-save)
           ("S-<insert>"  . yank)
           )))

For more information :
(describe-function 'use-package)
(describe-function 'bind-key)


That's perfect, now all I need is to mark text using shift and arrow.  I assume I can do that  by assigning something to set-mark-command but not sure how.

Try cua-mode for the shift-selection

Thanks for the pointer but how do I go about tryng cua-mode?

I guess you mean this - https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/CUA-Bindings.html
